# Intersection of two x-array datasets

Tags: pandas, geopandas, python-xarray

I have two x-array datasets.

- One is called `foo` and has the dimensions `x,y,time` with variables `a,b,c,d`.
- The second is called `bar` and is the result of a time series analysis on `foo`.

  - this only has dimensions `x,y` and a single variable `e` where all values of `e` fall between `0` and `1`.

I would like to use `bar` to filter or limit the amount of `x,y,time` data-entries being processed in `foo`. Only `x,y,time`'s with `e > 0.8` at each `x.y` should be considered here-on.

I'm still fairly new to X-arrays. My question is whether a 'set operation' mentality of somehow AND-ing or intersecting two-xarray datasets and expecting a smaller dataset is a realistic way to reason about x-arrays?

Here is what I have so far.

`foo = loadDataset()`
`bar = perform_timeseries_analysis()`
`filtered_bar = bar > 0.8`
`#TODO: Use bar to reduce the size of foo`

Comment: you should provide us with an example input and a desired ouput. also you should show us what you tried. [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: The problem with what I've tried is that I've reached a dead end limited by my understanding of X-arrays. What I have encourages people to run with my short sighted thought process to solving this problems. I've tried using .where() and bracket notation filters that give me true or flase values

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is what ended up working for me

```
import numpy as np
from example import *

foo = loadDataset() #returns dataset
bar = perform_timeseries_analysis(foo) # returns dataset
mutable_temp = bar.timeseries.values  
mutable_temp[mutable_temp < 0.8] = np.nan 
mutable_temp[np.isfinite(mutable_temp)] = 0
mask = mutable_temp.astype(np.float32)
foo = foo + mask
```